# Holes/ missing layers (after retraction) in 3d printed objects

Tags: extrusion

My printed objects have horizontal holes in them (as seen I the picture below):
[image]

This doesn't only look bad it also makes the object break at the seems.

Looking carefully at the printing process I can see that after a retraction there's a small amount of time the hotend isn't extruding plastic.

Material: PLA, Printer Robo 3D R1+, Slicer: Cura

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(answering my own question)

The problem was the extrusion distance settings in Cura's advanced tab, reducing the value to 1.5mm solved the problem.

Other problems with the same symptoms:

- Partially blocked hotend nozzle.
- Incorrectly configured steps per mm for the extruder motor - [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YUPfBJz3I6Y) shows how to test and configure this.